# Better Than HTML Tables For HTML Forms?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm renovating a legacy Java based web site.   I've already greatly reduced the number of tags used on the front end by using CSS to do the graphic lay out of the "screens".  Is there a CSS tag that will replace HTML tables that makes a good grid for HTML forms?   Does it significantly reduce the number of tags?  Is it reliable in most of the main browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are actually prevalently used to align forms. You take out the borders with `<table borders='0'>`. They are pretty reliable for aligning because the table cells in different rows line up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still probably want to use `<table>` tags for actual grid/table elements.  But, you could consider using something like Javascript [grid/table plugins](http://datatables.net/) for tables... for styling, and functionality.

I would suggest using `<ul>` and `<li>` elements (and then setting CSS rules for those elements,) when formatting `<form>` elements, though.  If it doesn't seem to be working out... you can still leave the `<form>` in a table; over the past decade, however, browser support for CSS has made it a lot easier to use HTML lists instead of tables for formatting things like forms.